# openshift laravel 5.0 uploaded images deleted after pushing the changes

Tags: php, laravel-5, openshift

Every time I push something in openshift, all my uploaded files are deleted. I'm not sure where openshift moved them. All i see on the admin panel is broken images.  Anyone encountered this problem?

I've tried linking the public/uploads folder to `OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` using the deploy script, unfortunately it didn't work.  What's wrong with my deploy script?

```
ln -sf ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}uploads   ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}public/uploads
ln -sf ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}levels   ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}public/levels
ln -sf ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}messages   ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}public/messages
ln -sf ${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}cards   ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}public/cards
```

Comment: I think you have the wrong order in your 'ln' command. You want to link the public directories into the data dir, not the other way around.

Comment: @Hardy ln command syntax is `ln [OPTION]... TARGET [...] [LINKNAME [...]]`

Answer (score 1):

You should move (`mv`) your files into the `$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR` after you upload them into your application directory.

Check: https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-filesystem.html#__code_data_code

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've already figured it out. What I did was, I made a symbolic link of openshift data directories on the runtime app.

Comment: i didn't undestand.please mail me from here.. i need it.. ............http://www.sabin.info.np/?section=6