# Photo upload, photos being deleted after every deployment

Tags: openshift

We have photo upload functionality in our App. They are being deleted after every deployment (which is expected as we are uploading to deployment directory).

But is there any way I can retain them after deployment? Maybe upload to a directory out side deployment directory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [openshift laravel 5.0 uploaded images deleted after pushing the changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33301345/openshift-laravel-5-0-uploaded-images-deleted-after-pushing-the-changes)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the `${OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR}` to be used as persistent storage. Details about this environment variable (and other ones) can be found [here](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-environment-variables.html#directory-variables).

Comment: I saw the documentation and I know I can use that environment variable. But how can I symlink that or how can I actually access the files in that folder from the application.

Comment: Whatever your application is, you should be able to use the path to the directory and work with the data in your code. How exactly are you trying to read & write the files there (post a code sample here)?